# Asp.net Required Field Validators do not work on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Product_Image")%>'></asp:Image>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnFileUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-file btn au-btn-load " BackColor="DarkBlue" ForeColor="White" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnFileUpdate_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FUImage" runat="server" CssClass="form-control-file" Style="padding-top: 30px" />
                            </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="row form-group">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblPName" runat="server" class=" form-control-label font-weight-bold">Product Name</asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("Product_Name") %>' ValidationGroup="validate"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="R1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="*This feild must be filled." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row form-group">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" class=" form-control-label font-weight-bold">Description</asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%#Bind("Product_Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            <br />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row form-group">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" class=" form-control-label font-weight-bold">Quantity</asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Product_Quantity") %>' TextMode="Number" min="1" ValidationGroup="validate" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ErrorMessage="*This feild must be filled." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </div>
```

Before clicking button, if i leave the box empty and moves to another box, it displays error message to fill the box. But When i click on submit button , if text box is still empty it saves null value and does not display error message.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-sm" Style="background-color: darkblue; color: white" Width="80px" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="validate" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your complete code? So will be able to spot the missed part easily. Here I am not able to find code snippet for "Submit" button.

Comment: I'm trying to check what's problem with my question. The complete code is note visible here. I don't know why. When i click on edit i can see complete code that i posted.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-sm" Style="background-color: darkblue; color: white" Width="80px" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="validate" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>

Comment: Don't paste your code directly as text. There's dedicated placeholder for the code snippet. Select that one then pastes your code. Then it will appear as formatted code in bordered section.

Comment: I'm pasting the code in code section but still it appears same like this

Comment: You can highlight your code lines and press ctrl+K... or put three backticks ``` above and below your code lines... or add four spaces in front of every line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you have already added the following snippet.
So under your submit button click event, you need to check IsValid.

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsValid)
    {}
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I have used my above code in two asp pages. One where i saved the information and in other one i edited that information. Validators work on save page but do not working on edit page. I also changed the validation group name. I'm also using java script for deletion confirmation on edit page.